# MCSwipeTableViewCell detailTextLabel not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using MCSwipeTableViewCell library but running into a problem. 
I set my detailTextLabel but it's not showing up.

Anyone know what might be causing this? I enlarge the height of the row to make sure nothing is getting covered up. The main textLabel is showing up perfectly, though I want to find a way to reposition it programmatically since autolayout doesn't work with this library.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I fixed the problem. It was caused because I set the cell type to custom in the storyboard. All I had to was set it to subtitle.